# problemas com criação da stored procedure mssql

Tags: sql-server

recentemente resolvi mudar de uso de banco de dados do MySQL server para o mssql(sql server versão 2012)
até ai tudo bem o que acontece é que algumas coisas não conseguir refazer-las

se alguém poder me ajudar a terminar a procedure pois onde se encontra " comentado " aparece erro de sintaxe

vou posta o código que eu tentando recriar(CODIGO ORIGINAL)

> Here is the google translate results:
>
> I recently decided to change database usage from MySQL server to mssql
>   (sql server version 2012) so far so well what happens is some things
>   can't redo them
>
> if anyone can help me finish the procedure because where is
>   "commented" appears syntax error
>
> I will post the code that I am trying to recreate (ORIGINAL CODE)

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ProcGetMessageMemberInfo_One`(IN @PlayerUID int, IN friend_uid int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE u_id,
            unknown_1,
            unknown_2,
            unknown_3,
            unknown_4,
            unknown_5,
            unknown_6,
            flag_1,
            flag_state,
            player_flag INT(10) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE nickname VARCHAR(23);
    DECLARE apelido_in VARCHAR(12);
    DECLARE FINISHED INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE MSN_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
    (   SELECT  a.nick,
                b.uid_friend,
                b.apelido,
                b.unknown1,
                b.unknown2,
                b.unknown3,
                b.unknown4,
                b.unknown5,
                b.unknown6,
                b.flag1,
                b.state_flag,
                @Flag := 1 AS FLAG_PLAYER
        FROM account a, pangya_friend_list b
        WHERE b.uid = @PlayerUID AND a.uid = b.uid_friend AND b.uid_friend = friend_uid
    )
    UNION ALL
    (   SELECT  a.nick,
                @uid_fr := c.member_uid as uid_friend,
                @apel := "" as apelido,
                @unk1 := -1 as unknwon1,
                @unk2 := 0 as unknwon2,
                @unk3 := -1 as unknwon3,
                @unk4 := 0 as unknwon4,
                @unk5 := 0 as unknwon5,
                @unk6 := 0 as unknown6,
                @flag1 := -1 as flag1,
                @flag4 := 0 as state_flag,
                @Flag := 2 AS FLAG_PLAYER
        FROM account a, pangya_guild_member c
        WHERE c.GUILD_UID = (SELECT i.GUILDINDEX FROM Pangya_Member i, pangya_guild_member j WHERE i.UID = @PlayerUID AND i.GUILD_ID = j.GUILD_ID AND j.GUILD_MEMBER_UID = @PlayerUID AND j.GUILD_MEMBER_STATUS < 9)
        AND c.member_uid = a.uid AND c.member_uid = friend_uid AND c.MEMBER_STATE_FLAG != 9
    );

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
        FOR NOT FOUND SET FINISHED = 1;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_msn_one`;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp_msn_one`(nick VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL,
                                      uid INT(10) NOT NULL,
                                      apelido VARCHAR(12),
                                      unknown1 INT(10),
                                      unknown2 INT(10),
                                      unknown3 INT(10),
                                      unknown4 INT(10),
                                      unknown5 INT(10),
                                      unknown6 INT(10),
                                      flag1 INT(10),
                                      state_flag INT(10),
                                      FLAG_PLAYER INT(10));
    OPEN MSN_CURSOR;

    MSN_LOOP : LOOP
        FETCH MSN_CURSOR INTO nickname, u_id, apelido_in, unknown_1, unknown_2, unknown_3,
                              unknown_4, unknown_5, unknown_6, flag_1, flag_state, player_flag;

        IF FINISHED = 1 THEN
            LEAVE MSN_LOOP;
        END IF;

        IF (SELECT uid FROM temp_msn_one WHERE UID = u_id) IS NOT NULL THEN
            UPDATE temp_msn_one SET FLAG_PLAYER = FLAG_PLAYER + player_flag WHERE UID = u_id;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO temp_msn_one VALUES(nickname, u_id, apelido_in, unknown_1, unknown_2, unknown_3,
                                        unknown_4, unknown_5, unknown_6, flag_1, flag_state, player_flag);
        END IF;
    END LOOP MSN_LOOP;

    CLOSE MSN_CURSOR;

    SELECT * FROM temp_msn_one;
END
```

replica do codigo acima em mssql

> replica of the code above in mssql

```
    USE [DB_Pangya]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ProcGetMessageMemberInfo_One]    Script Date: 02/08/2019 13:04:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcGetMessageMemberInfo_One] 

@PLAYER_UID INT,
 @friend_uid int
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @u_id INT =0;
    DECLARE @unknown_1 INT =0;
    DECLARE @unknown_2 INT =0;
    DECLARE @unknown_3 INT =0;
    DECLARE @unknown_4 INT =0;
    DECLARE @unknown_5 INT =0;
    DECLARE @unknown_6 INT =0;
    DECLARE @flag_1 INT =0;
    DECLARE @flag_state INT =0;
    DECLARE @player_flag INT = 0;
    DECLARE @nickname VARCHAR(23);
    DECLARE @apelido_in VARCHAR(12);
    DECLARE @FINISHED INT = 0;
    DECLARE @uid_fr INT  =0;
    DECLARE @apel VARCHAR(23) = '';
    DECLARE @unk1 INT =  -1;
    DECLARE @unk2 INT =  0;
    DECLARE @unk3 INT =  -1;
    DECLARE @unk4 INT =  0;
    DECLARE @unk5 INT =  0;
    DECLARE @unk6 INT =  0;
    DECLARE @flag1 INT =  -1;
    DECLARE @flag4 INT =  0;
    DECLARE @Flag INT =  2;

    DECLARE MSN_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
    (   SELECT  a.Nickname,
                b.Friend_UID,
                b.Friend_Nick,
                b.UN,
                b.UN2,
                b.UN3,
                b.UN4,
                b.UN5,
                b.UN6,
                b.flag1,
                b.StatusFlag,
                 1 AS FLAG_PLAYER
        FROM Pangya_Member a, pangya_friend_list b
        WHERE b.uid = @PLAYER_UID AND a.uid = b.Friend_UID AND b.Friend_UID = @friend_uid
    )

     UNION ALL
    (   SELECT  a.Nickname,
                c.GUILD_MEMBER_UID as uid_friend,
                @apel as apelido,
                @unk1  as unknwon1,
                @unk2  as unknwon2,
                @unk3  as unknwon3,
                @unk4 as unknwon4,
                @unk5 as unknwon5,
                @unk6  as unknown6,
                @flag1 as flag1,
                @flag4 as state_flag,
                @Flag  AS FLAG_PLAYER
        FROM pangya_member a, pangya_guild_member c
        WHERE c.GUILD_ID  = (SELECT i.GUILDINDEX FROM Pangya_Member i, pangya_guild_member j WHERE i.UID = @PLAYER_UID AND i.GUILDINDEX = j.GUILD_ID AND j.GUILD_MEMBER_UID = @PLAYER_UID AND j.GUILD_MEMBER_STATUS < 9)
         and c.GUILD_MEMBER_UID = a.uid AND c.GUILD_MEMBER_UID = @friend_uid AND c.GUILD_MEMBER_STATUS != 9
    );

    --DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @FINISHED = 1;


   IF (OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#temp_msn_one') IS NOT NULL)
     DROP TABLE #temp_msn_one
     create table #temp_msn_one(nick VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL,
                                      uid INT NOT NULL,
                                      apelido VARCHAR(12),
                                      unknown1 INT,
                                      unknown2 INT,
                                      unknown3 INT,
                                      unknown4 INT,
                                      unknown5 INT,
                                      unknown6 INT,
                                      flag1 INT,
                                      state_flag INT,
                                      FLAG_PLAYER INT);

--OPEN MSN_CURSOR;

  --  MSN_LOOP : LOOP
        --FETCH MSN_CURSOR INTO @nickname, @u_id, @apelido_in, @unknown_1, @unknown_2, @unknown_3,
        --                    @unknown_4, @unknown_5, @unknown_6, @flag_1, @flag_state, @player_flag;

  --      IF @FINISHED = 1 begin
        --  LEAVE MSN_LOOP;
        --END

  --      IF (SELECT uid FROM #temp_msn_one WHERE UID = @u_id) IS NOT NULL begin
        --  UPDATE #temp_msn_one SET FLAG_PLAYER = FLAG_PLAYER + @player_flag WHERE UID = @u_id;
        --ELSE
        --  INSERT INTO #temp_msn_one VALUES(@nickname, @u_id, @apelido_in, @unknown_1, @unknown_2, @unknown_3,
        --                    @unknown_4, @unknown_5, @unknown_6, @flag_1, @flag_state, @player_flag);
        --END
  --  END LOOP MSN_LOOP;

    --CLOSE MSN_CURSOR;

    SELECT * FROM #temp_msn_one;

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá substitui a parte que comentaste por este código...não criei a tabela para validar, mas será algo por aí. Valida e dá feedback.

```
    DECLARE MSN_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM #temp_msn_one;

    OPEN MSN_CURSOR  
    FETCH NEXT FROM MSN_CURSOR INTO @nickname, @u_id, @apelido_in, @unknown_1, @unknown_2, @unknown_3,
                                @unknown_4, @unknown_5, @unknown_6, @flag_1, @flag_state, @player_flag

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        IF EXISTS (SELECT uid FROM #temp_msn_one WHERE UID = @u_id)
          UPDATE #temp_msn_one SET FLAG_PLAYER = FLAG_PLAYER + @player_flag WHERE UID = @u_id;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO #temp_msn_one VALUES(@nickname, @u_id, @apelido_in, @unknown_1, @unknown_2, @unknown_3,
                           @unknown_4, @unknown_5, @unknown_6, @flag_1, @flag_state, @player_flag);
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM MSN_CURSOR INTO @nickname, @u_id, @apelido_in, @unknown_1, @unknown_2, @unknown_3,
                                @unknown_4, @unknown_5, @unknown_6, @flag_1, @flag_state, @player_flag 
    END 

    CLOSE MSN_CURSOR  
    DEALLOCATE MSN_CURSOR
```

Comment: eu vi que  faltou o " SELECT * FROM #temp_msn_one; " e o "END" para encerrar o codigo, será se o procedimento será criado?

Comment: esta parte também foi comentada, sei que existe diferença entre as duas linguagens

Comment: sou meio leigo e não sei como faço isso funcionar > DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @FINISHED = 1; <

Comment: Precisas do select final para alguma coisa? Eu tipicamente quando quero utilizar uma SP para criar ou editar, crio uma variável INT = 0, depois fazes SET 1 se fizer update e SET 2 se fizer insert, e retornas esse valor da variável.

Comment: Obrigado ! tecnicamente funcionou, mas houve um erro ao tentar consultar a proc

Comment: Não precisas do DECLARE... o que controla no loop o fim do cursor é a linha "WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0".

Comment: Mas o select que referiste na tua primeira questão vai precisar retornar é os teus dados editados, nem olhei para a lógica do que fazia...só converti o código que dava erro....

Comment: mas de qualquer forma já ajudou e marquei a resposta como aceitação !

Comment: quando executar o erro se refere ao cursor, pois o já existe um cursor " MSN_CURSOR " bem no inicio do codigo e baixo e declarado novamente e assim causa um erro ao tentar consultar

Comment: Pois tem, a linha DECLARE MSN_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM #temp_msn_one; podes remover.